# Detect whether a specific app has any menu opened

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.3-rio

How can I detect whether a specific app (where the app's window handle and process-ID are known) currently has any **MENU opened** (main menu or popup menu)?

I have researched this but did not find anything.

Comment: use `SetWinEventHook` with `EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART / EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND / EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART / EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND`

Comment: You should also consider that some menus aren't implemented using the system menu APIs

Comment: A standard menu is of class [#32768](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes), you can enumerate thread windows of the window of the application that you suspect to have an active menu. To verify, you can send a [MN_GETHMENU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/mn-gethmenu) to the window.

Comment: "A standard menu" -> "A standard menu window"

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am not sure what you mean by "enumerate thread windows of the window of the application". Could you provide an example? (I have the window handle of the application window).

Comment: You can use GetWindowThreadProcessId to retrieve the thread identifier of the application window to pass to EnumThreadWindows which enumerates top level thread windows. If anyone is a #32768, then there's an active menu.

Comment: I posted some example code in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible implementation might involve enumerating top level windows of the thread that the target application window belongs, to search if any one of them is the menu window class. This is '#32768' as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes).

Following example does the same for Windows 7 calculator in a timer event handler. The example outputs a debug string if the program's menu or context menu is open.

```pascal
function EnumThreadWindowsCallback(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  MenuWndClass = '#32768';
var
  ClassName: array[0..256] of Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName)) = Length(MenuWndClass)) and
      (ClassName = MenuWndClass) then begin
    PBoolean(lparam)^ := True;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Wnd: HWND;
  ThrId: DWORD;
  MenuWnd: Boolean;
begin
  Wnd := FindWindow('CalcFrame', 'Calculator');
  if Wnd <> 0 then begin
    ThrId := GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd);
    MenuWnd := False;
    EnumThreadWindows(ThrId, @EnumThreadWindowsCallback, LPARAM(@MenuWnd));
    if MenuWnd then
      OutputDebugString('active menu');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works with both the main menu and context menu. Should I send you a link to the finished product? (In a few days). May I mention you in the About dialog?

Comment: You may do so of course. Technically, the license the code is under is mentioned in the bottom right of every SO page, which is CC-BY-SA-4.0, which I don't exactly know what it is. :)